# Font size change option in Ios application

Tags: iphone, ios

Application having option to change font size dynamically by user ,options like 14,17,20,23.

when user change font size dynamic, we need to change all views position as per new height of views.
 is this right way?

Answer (score 2):

you cant change all the fonts at once....

But i have find one more varient that is working for me nicely and also will help you...

I have made some recursive functions thy can help you..

follow following steps..

> **First create a class(BaseViewController) extended from UIViewController like in BaseViewController.h file**

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
```

**And in BaseViewController.m file write following code.**

```
-(void)changeFontsOfViewController:(CGFloat)size
{
    UIViewController * vv = [self viewControllerOfView:self.view];
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([vv class]) owner:vv options:nil];

    for (id object in objects)
    {
        [self changeFontOfView:object withSize:size];
    }

}

-(void)changeFontOfView:(UIView *)aView withSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    for (UIView *vv in [aView subviews])
    {

        if ([vv isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)vv;
            btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize];
        }
        else if ([vv isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)vv;
            [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize]];
        }
        else if ([vv isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
        {
            UITextView *txt = (UITextView *)vv;
            [txt setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize]];
        }
        else if ([vv isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *txt = (UITextField *)vv;
            [txt setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize]];
        }
        else if ([vv isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]||[vv isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
            if (aView.subviews.count == 0)return;
            [self changeFontOfView:vv  withSize:size];
        }
    }

}
```

> **Now your every viewController(RootViewController) will be extended from BaseViewController class like in RootViewController.h..**

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : BaseViewController
{

}
```

**when you want to change your font size call `changeFontOfView:withSize:` like...**

```
[self changeFontsOfViewController:14];
```

Please follow above steps carefully you will rock.......

Comment: sorry for late comments...I will try this method and update

Comment: Thanks...its not working for `UITableView''s Custom cell though ! any guesses ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but this is how I would do it:

**Make sure you have a class which is responsible for handling all your data** which you can access from everywhere within your project (Usually my `dataControllers` are referenced from my `AppDelegate`).

Then you **create a property that contains the different switchable font sizes** (Tipp: Create a `C typedef enum` if you want to call your fontsizes by name rather than numbers).

When you're doing this you may want to create more than 1 property because you probably have headers and subtitles and not everything should have the same fontsize right?

Now you want every related `UIControl` to be changed when this value is changed right? If you want to do so, **I would highly suggest using the [key-value-observer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) as it will do all the work for you after you changed the value.**